# How to place a widget in a Canvas widget in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, widget, tkinter-canvas

I want basically to be able to use a `Canvas` as a meta container for other widgets.

I want to divide my GUI into a left, center and middle section. Within each section I would like to be able to *place* widgets like: `Checkbutton`, `Button`, `Label`, etc.

How to place widgets in a Canvas widget?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your choices depend on what you're really trying to accomplish. Why is using a canvas preferable to using a frame?

You can easily add widgets to a canvas just like you do any other container, using pack or grid or place. when you do this, the items will not scroll when you scroll the canvas because they aren't actually part of the canvas.

The other choice is to create window objects on the canvas. You do this with the `create_window` method of the canvas. The advantage is, this window becomes part of the canvas and will scroll along with any other objects on the canvas. The downside is, your only option is absolute placement and you have to explicitly control the size of the widgets.

Comment: I've decided to go with the Frame widget instead. Can grid be specific to a frame, (versus the master "Frame")?

Comment: @thenickname: I don't understand your question. Grid is a geometry manager that works with every widget. You can use grid in the main window, in child frames, in canvases, etc.

Comment: I was under the impression that, if you were to apply grid to a frame, the grid addresses would be unique to that frame. In addition, any Frames you create in the master would be subject to the coordinates in the master grid. Is this true?

Comment: @thenickname: no, not true (though I don't fully understand what you said). Any container (toplevel window, frame, etc) needs a geometry manager to manage its children. The geometry manager for each container is distinct. Thus, the main window can use the grid or pack geometry manager, and internal frames can use the grid or pack geometry manager, and each of those will have distinct "addresses". You can put something in row 1, column 1 of a subframe, and something different in row 1, column 1 of the master, and those will be in two different places.