# Horizontal scrollbar in canvas in tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, canvas, tkinter, scrollbar

I'm trying to add a horizontal scrollbar in a canvas in tkinter. Here's what I did (ripped off from this tutorial- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_scrollbar.htm):

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
scrollbar = Scrollbar(root) 
scrollbar.pack( side = RIGHT, fill=Y )

mylist = Canvas(root, yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set, scrollregion= (0, 0, 5000, 5000))
for line in range(100):
   Label(mylist, text= "This is line number %s" %str(line)).pack()

mylist.pack( side = LEFT, fill = BOTH )
scrollbar.config( command = mylist.yview )



mainloop()
```

Here's what I'm getting:

[image: screenshot]

Unfortunately, moving the scrollbars does nothing. Could anyone help fix this please?

Comment: You can't scroll items packed or gridded in a canvas. Also, your question says horizontal but shows verticle. It's a little confusing.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080413/python-tkinter-place-a-widget-in-a-canvas-widget/4080471#4080471)