# Adding scrollbar to frame in customtkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I'm trying to learn customtkinter + tkinter by making a project, I found this code snippet online, needed help to understand how this could be implemented for a CTkinter frame instead of a Tkinter textbox.

```
import customtkinter, tkinter

app = customtkinter.CTk()
app.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
app.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

# create scrollable textbox
tk_textbox = tkinter.Text(app, highlightthickness=0)
tk_textbox.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

# create CTk scrollbar
ctk_textbox_scrollbar = customtkinter.CTkScrollbar(app, command=tk_textbox.yview)
ctk_textbox_scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")

# connect textbox scroll event to CTk scrollbar
tk_textbox.configure(yscrollcommand=ctk_textbox_scrollbar.set)

app.mainloop()
```

I tried replacing the textbox with a CTkinter Frame widget, it shows that yview is not an attribute of the frame

Comment: I can't speak to customtkinter frames, but vanilla tkinter frame widgets aren't scrollable as far as I know. It's likely that customtkinter frames *also* don't support this.

Comment: Sure thing. Sorry I don't have a solution for you. I was going to suggest that you try a `Canvas` instead of a `Frame`, but according to this answer from @BryanOakley, [that doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4080471/8512262) either.

Comment: @JRiggles,thanks will indeed try that

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CTkScrollableFrame instead of CTkFrame.

[CustomTkinter wiki - CTkScrollableFrame](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/wiki/CTkScrollableFrame)

Comment: Link-only answers have risk of link going dead. Please provide summary/steps from link to solve the problem.

Comment: I am not linking an example or instructions, I am referring to the official documentation for the package.